# Характеристики ПК для запуска Android - эмулятора (Lollipop)?

Tags: android, avd

Возникла проблема с запуском Android-эмулятора. Android 4 запускается, а 5 - нет.

Характеристики моего ноутбука:

- Intel Celeron N2840 (2.16 ГГц)
- RAM 4 ГБ
- Intel HD Graphics

Comment: Этого вполне должно хватать. Скорость загрузки на дефолтном эмуляторе будет не самая быстрая но вполне должен запускаться. Не могли бы вы более конкретно описать проблему.

Comment: Не запускается с каким сообщением?

Comment: ВЫ, когда задаёте характеристики эмулируемого устройства, задавайте самые низкие, не бойтесь, это не повлияет на работу 5 версии андройда, зато может повлиять на запуск, т.е. задавайте разрешение экрана самое низкое, устройство выберите samsung galaxy s, оперативки выделите 512 мб и всё должно заработать, а лучше используйте genymotions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте эмулятор Genymotion. Он намного быстрее и в нем больше возможностей.
[Официальный сайт](https://www.genymotion.com/)